# What subgroup of $S_4$ is this?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation

What is the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $\left(14\right)\left(23\right)$ and $\left(12\right)$?

I can see that they are both order 2, and they don't commute, but can't see where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take all "words" formed by the two elements.  The order of each is $2$.  The order of their product, $(1423)$, is $4$. Also, $(12)(1423)(12)=(1324)=(1423)^{-1}$. So we have   $\langle a,b\mid a^4,b^2,(ba)^2\rangle $.

This is $D_4$, the dihedral group.

There are at most $8$ elements because,  using $ba=a^{-1}b$, every word can be put in the form $a^mb^n$, with $0\le m\le3$ and $0\le n\le1$.

Comment: Ahh, I see! And to see the square behind it all, if we number the vertices clockwise as 1423, then the two generators are reflection along a diagonal, and reflection through a line which bisects two opposite sides! Thanks!

Comment: That's right:   the symmetries of a square.

Answer (score 0):

Where you go is to calculate products of those permutations and products of the products. When you can no longer generate anything new you will have the subgroup. (You may want to provide a proof then that you have them all.)

Here's a start:
$$
(14)(23)(12) = (1423)
$$
(multiplying from left to right).

Comment: I've tried this, and believe that: the group has order 6, it is not cyclic. Therefore, I believe that it is $S_3$. Can you confirm this? Think of any ways to test it?

Comment: My answer shows you an element of order $4$ in the subgroup, so you should check your permutation arithmetic.

Comment: @EthanBolker, in your product, 2 goes to 4, not to 3. So $(14)(23)(12) = (1324)$. But you still have an element of order 4

Comment: @miraunpajaro You  multiply right to left (thinking function application). I multiply left to right, and said so (easier to do the formal computations with cycles). Either convention leads to the same group,of course.

Comment: @EthanBolker you're right of course. I didn't finish reading the sentence haha